# DotNetOpenAuth Oauth Google Calendar

Tags: c#, dotnetopenauth

I have knowledge of the Oauth process but dont have a clue where to start coding.

I have looked at the DotNetOpenAuth site, downloaded the examples and have run the Google Contacts example.

I would like to do something similar but with a Google Calendar but cannot even begin to start. I have got as far as creating a new project, importing the relevent DotNetOpenAuth dlls and have been staring at it like a chimp (chump) for the last 3 hours.

Does anyone know of any good tutorials or examples to give me a starting point?

Hopefully someone can throw me a rope.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have the Google Contacts OAuth sample running, that means you've reached the end of where DotNetOpenAuth's scope will take you.  You now need to read the Google Calendar documentation/API to find out how to create your own HTTP requests to access Google Calendar.  DotNetOpenAuth's sample should show you how to use OAuth to sign these requests just as it does for Google Contacts.